# Saving the indices along with array values and timestamp

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

The code selects some values of an input matrix under a certain criterion and saves the array values and the timestamp in a CSV file. However, I would also like to save the indices of the values which meet the criterion in the file. For instance, 0.00283663 should be saved in indices as (0,0), 0.00366354 as (0,1), and so on.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import csv 


def get_neighbor_indices(position, dimensions):
    '''
    dimensions is a shape of np.array
    '''
    i, j = position
    indices = [(i+1,j), (i-1,j), (i,j+1), (i,j-1)]
    return [
        (i,j) for i,j in indices
        if i>=0 and i<dimensions[0]
            and j>=0 and j<dimensions[1]
        ]

def iterate_array(init_i, init_j, arr, condition_func):
    '''
    arr is an instance of np.array
    condition_func is a function (value) => boolean
    '''
    indices_to_check = [(init_i,init_j)]
    checked_indices = set()
    result = []
    t0 = None
    t1 = None
    timestamps = []
    while indices_to_check:
        pos = indices_to_check.pop()
        if pos in checked_indices:
            continue
        item = arr[pos]
        checked_indices.add(pos)
        if condition_func(item):
            result.append(item)
            t1=time.time()
            if(t0==None):
                t0=t1
            timestamps.append(t1-t0)
            indices_to_check.extend(
                get_neighbor_indices(pos, arr.shape)
            )
    return result,timestamps

P1=np.array([[0.00283663, 0.00366354, 0.00409428, 0.00413427, 0.00460583,
        0.00561729, 0.00534243, 0.00606901, 0.00716933, 0.00589545],
       [0.002966  , 0.00389675, 0.00819014, 0.0033527 , 0.00279446,
        0.00389331, 0.005467  , 0.0074498 , 0.0061827 , 0.0019047 ],
       [0.00382798, 0.00706568, 0.00771079, 0.0051791 , 0.00868578,
        0.00299466, 0.0039018 , 0.00442754, 0.00242183, 0.00296557],
       [0.00688767, 0.00321205, 0.00660123, 0.01484231, 0.0049053 ,
        0.00633156, 0.01187461, 0.00594399, 0.01242215, 0.00715901],
       [0.00430382, 0.00351602, 0.00190091, 0.00506819, 0.00754771,
        0.01005015, 0.00786365, 0.0021402 , 0.01038063, 0.00643014],
       [0.00518718, 0.01032835, 0.00474036, 0.00518982, 0.00426777,
        0.00386   , 0.00911095, 0.00588235, 0.00181438, 0.00853461],
       [0.00961443, 0.00694841, 0.00380918, 0.00544034, 0.00680266,
        0.00589402, 0.00439172, 0.00777265, 0.0098635 , 0.00715645],
       [0.00339641, 0.00254593, 0.00323944, 0.00610313, 0.00335935,
        0.00237189, 0.00827397, 0.003621  , 0.0061203 , 0.01048242],
       [0.01107988, 0.00101446, 0.00837964, 0.00741175, 0.00447646,
        0.00505653, 0.003778  , 0.00407837, 0.00190113, 0.00643703],
       [0.00824774, 0.00530632, 0.00234013, 0.00662338, 0.00784433,
        0.00283537, 0.00516266, 0.00350584, 0.00642597, 0.01420954]])

timestamps,T=iterate_array(0,0, P1, lambda x : x < 0.007)
print(T)
print(timestamps)
header = ['T','Timestamps']
data = [timestamps, T]

with open('Data_0.007.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write the data
    writer.writerows(zip(timestamps, T))
```

Comment: your `timestamps` structure is only one flat list, you have lost all notion of 2D structure, so what do you expect ?

Comment: @azro It should basically store the indices of the values of in array ```P1``` which meet the given criterion i.e. x < 0.007.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have the index information accessible via the local variable `pos` in `iterate_array`. Simply append `pos` to some new list when you add to your `result` and `timestamps` lists (when `condition_func(item)` is `True`).

Comment: I tried ```pos.append(item)``` in ```condition_func(item)``` and got the following error: ```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'```

Comment: You must make a new output storage list, like you have already with `result` and `timestamps`, then append `pos` to it. You would help yourself by at least adding some print statements during your loops so you can see what your code does.